# PHP formatting grouped thousands to non grouped

Tags: php, laravel, numbers

I have a system where you input an amount and it calculates some stuff and puts it into the database.

However, what I've noticed is that multiple people enter different formats.

Some people enter:
3474,12832752
And some people enter:
3474.12832752 <--- correct
And then some people do this one:
3,747.12832752

Now how would I do so the two that are incorrect formats to the correct one?

Previously, I just did so "," is replaced with "." to solve the first incorrect one, but recently people have been doing the last incorrect one where thousands are grouped.

How would I successfully format the two incorrect ones to the correct one?

Comment: So what desired output you want for `3,747.12832752`?

Comment: You could have a text above the input telling people what format to input and then only allow numbers and dots in the actual input field.

Answer (score 2):

In front :

- With jQuery, allow your input to accept only ".", and disallow ","

In Controller :

- If user didn't have javascript on his browser, check if input contain ",", if it does, return an error with a message to tell user only dots are accepted.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

- Don't allow your users to enter a value in the "wrong" format, just reject it
- recognize the "wrong" formatted values via regex and replace the wrong characters with the correct ones

Comment: The second alternative could be quite impossible. If someone writes "123,123", they could mean "123123" or do they mean "123.123". I would go for your first alternative, just reject it.

Comment: I guess you're right, i wouldn't recommend it either, but it is an option if (put reason in here) the restictions may not be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

In the front-end you can use some jquery plugins to  validate/force the format before sending it, check [jQuery Inputmask.](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)

In case you are forced to format the data on the backend, you can create a [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers) function like this:

```
function correctNumber($number){
    return substr_replace(preg_replace('/[.,]/', '', $number), ".", 4, 0);
}
```

Then  in your controller you can simply format the number on the proper way:

```
echo correctNumber("3474,12832752");
//3474.12832752

echo correctNumber("3747.12832752");
//3474.12832752
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these formats is wrong. While the second is the standard American standard for writing decimal numbers, a lot of European countries and maye others places too use a comma instead of a dot as the decimal separator. Both way of writing are thus valid. The later is also perfectly valid since it's a standard way of writing numbers on paper.

So, if you don't explicitly and visibly inform your users that numeric entries should be in a given format, they are in their right to use the one they are accustomed to.

Your opitions here are to either make it clear that only numeric values without any non-digit character except for a dot to separate the decimal part are allowed or to design a process to convert these different writing :

```
function format_number($value) {
    $comma = strpos($value, ',');
    $dot = strpos($value, '.');
    if ($dot === false AND $comma !== false AND strrpos($value, ',') == $comma) {
        $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value);
    }
    return str_replace(',', '', $value);
}
```

I checked it and it returns American writing for your three cases.